# Event performed before binding and fired after binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-events

I'm having some strange problems with event bindings in JQuery. We've got many inputs that we'd like to know if their values are changed by the user. I attach their events these way:

```
$(document).on("change", ".myClass", changed);
```

But sometimes we have to perform automatic changes over those fields, so I unbind those events, perform the changes and bind the events again in order to avoid change triggerings in these updates:

```
$(document).off("change", ".myClass");
$(".myClass").val(whatever);
$(document).on("change", ".myClass", changed);
```

But, if we click in one of these inputs after this last process we get that the change event fires even if the field hadn't attached any event when it was updated. We know that change event does not fire until the field loses the focus but we don't uderstand this behaviour.

Any help or clarification would be apreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Sorry, I meant changed instead of change().

Comment: You need to give the delegated event handler the *reference* of the function, not the *return value* of the function: `$(document).on('change', '.myClass', changed)`. Also note that your logic is moot anyway, as programmatically changing the value of an element does not raise a `change` event, see: https://jsfiddle.net/2185v3z5/

Comment: I see in your example that you're right but the raising of the event happends in my code, so I have to supose that I have a problem that I have not seen. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Change top line from

```
$(document).on("change", ".myClass", changed());
```

to

```
$(document).on("change", ".myClass", changed);
```

You are calling the method `changed()` and providing the return value from the `changed()` method.

Answer (score 1):

A function name with parenthesis like `changed()` calls the function immediately. That means the third argument is really passing in the return value of your `changed` function. You should change the line to:

```
$(document).on("change", ".myClass", changed);
```

Now your `changed` function will only fire when the event occurs.